# Best way to keep elements inside DIV not to inherit page styles

Tags: javascript, html

I am using CKEditor to allow user to post some rich content as comment. But while displaying I am using DIV as parent and throwing all content inside it. So, obviously it inherits all the CSS of page. I want to prevent that, below are options I have

1. Avoid generic styles like `p, div { ... }`.
2. For the DIV assign an ID and reset all styles applied on page for that DIV.
3. Use IFrame to display content. (This seems a good solution for me but I am trying to IFrames as much as I can).

Any **`new suggestions`** on this please?

Comment: Your options are the answers to the question, essentially.

Comment: Use 1 **and** 2. Don't do 3 as in don't do drugs, it seems enjoying but you shouldn't do it.

Comment: @rac Yeah, I know but first 2 options are like very tedious and will run into more tedious works when my stylesheet grows.

Comment: @devqon Yeah, I am trying to avoid IFrames :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the **BEM methodology** for your CSS. Block-Element-Modifier has been the go-to solution in all my work, including the stylesheets of a company with $1B+ in revenue and some three hundred engineers.

Under BEM you'll end up with:

```
.site-search {} /* Block */
.site-search__field {} /* Element */
.site-search--full {} /* Modifier */
```

In this case, your comments section could become a `.comment` block, with some elements and modifiers to style things inside it.